# Looking at one's tzitzit during kiddush levana

Tags: sources-mekorot, tzitzis, kiddush-levanah, kaparot

In some siddurim it writes to look at one's tzitzit during birchat halevana and kaparot.
What is the reason for this?

Comment: Both are connected to teshuva and perhaps looking at ones tzitzis is the idea of recommitting oneself to keeping the mitzvos either on a greater level or without previous faults?

Comment: @Dude Could be...

Answer (score 3):

In the shalmei simcha it brings from rav shlomo zalman Aurbach the reason for the minhag is to hint that since in the future the moon will be as bright as the sun, there will be a chiyuv to wear tzitzis at night. The only reason there's no chiyuv at night is because the verse says you shall see them, and at night you cant see them, but when the moon will be as bright as the sun, you'll be able to see them.

Answer (score 2):

The Be'er Heitev says (O"Ch 426:8) in the name of the Ariza"l that one should shake out his clothes after kiddush levana.

The Kaf Hachayim addresses this more in depth and says (O"Ch 35:22):

> אחר ברכת הלבנה צריך לנער את שולי הבגדים כדי להבריח החיצונים והקליפות שנבראו מקטרוג הלבנה, ויאמר שלש פעמים שלום עליכם, ויכוין שלא יהיה עוד קטרוג כמו שקטרגה בראשונה דאי אפשר לשני מלכים ונמעטה, דמכאן ואילך יהיה שלום, מ"ש דף קנ"ו ע"ב, ועוד טעם אחר, על כי אמרינן תפול עליהם אימתה ופחד, ועיין במשבצות זהב, ושלמי חגיגה, וקיצור של"ה, ואש"ל, ואליהו זוטא, ומהכא נפקא ענין הוצאת הציציות, דאעיקרא הוא לנער כנפות הטלית כנזכר ואגב מנשקן, ומי שלא ידע מזה עושה הטפל עיקר, דמנשק הציציות בלבד ואינו מנערו, אלא תרוויהו צריכי
>
> After kiddush levana he should shake out the edges of his clothes in order to chase away the outsiders (?) and he should say 'shalom aleichem' three times... And from here comes the *inyan* of taking his tzitzis out, the main purpose is to shake out the corners of his tallis, as was mentioned, and along the way he kisses them [the strings]. And one who doesn't know the reason, makes the secondary purpose the main purpose, as he kisses his tzitzis but doesn't shake it, rather he must do both.

So, the purpose of taking out one's tzitzis is to shake out the 'outsiders', not doing that (and only taking out/ looking at one's tzitzis) ignores the main purpose.

The Pri Etz Chaim (who was the student of the Ariza"l) also brings this in the Ariza"l's name, and explains why specifically tzitzis (שער ר"ח פרק ג'):

> וצריך לנער שולי בגדיו, להבריח את החיצונים הנעשין מקטרוג הלבנה. (ומורי ז"ל היה מנער כנפות הטלית קטן, כי הוא בגד המלכות כנודע)
>
> And he must shake out the edges of his clothes, in order to chase out the outsiders (?) which are made by the moon's complaint [*I think this refers to the midrash where the moon complained that it and the sun can't be the same size, but I'm not sure]. (And my master z"l [i.e. the Ariza"l] would shake out the corners of his tzitzis, because it is the kingly garment, as is known)

Comment: This also addresses the question linked below, which is slightly different but was marked as a duplicate of this question. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/139020/why-do-we-shake-our-tzitzit-after-kiddush-levana