# Why do we shake our tzitzit after kiddush levana?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, tzitzis, kiddush, kiddush-levanah

I have just said Kiddush Levanah and was told that i should shake my Tzitzit immediately afterwards...are there any specific Kabbalistic reasons for this?

Comment: Not sure it's a duplicate. This question is about shaking, not looking. See footnote 26 [here](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/how-to-say-kiddush-levana/).

Comment: I've answered the other question in a way that it answers this one as well