What is the reason for shaking the Tzitzis in the blessing of the Levana?
I have seen in the siddurim (Ashkenazi, Sfard) that the fringes of the Tzitzis are shaken at the end of the blessing of the Levana. What is the reason and the source of this? Does it mean a real Talit Katan? And those who don't wear a tassel at night, should they shake the pockets, the belt area of ​​the pants or the ends of the shirt? And if you wear a Talit Katan, should the wings be taken out and the tassels (Ptilot) themselves shaken or the place where the hole where the wicks come out is located? And is it necessary to bother to do so for those whose tassels are inserted or is it enough to shake the outer garment (shirt or pants)?

See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/137076/looking-at-ones-tzitzit-during-kiddush-levana
